# MySQL - Select Dates that are 1 week intervals from today

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL db that stores orders, and has a date field that gets populated when the order reaches a certain point.

I want to create a cron job that checks for all orders where this date is in multiples of 'weeks' ago.  For example:

Date stored: 12/1/2012

this row would be returned if the cron job triggered on the following days:

12/8/2012

12/15/2012

12/22/2012

12/29/2012

etc...

How do i structure the MySQL query to fetch data in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), my_date) % 7 = 0
```